# add the page number next to the reference

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing

I am using KOMA-script in lyx for my thesis. I would like to add the page number next to the reference in bibliography. Some thing like this:

1. S. J. Young, G. Evermann, M. J. F. Gales, T. Hain, D. Kershaw, G. Moore,
   J. Odell, D. Ollason, D. Povey, V. Valtchev, and P. C. Woodland, The HTK
   Book, version 3.4. Cambridge, UK: Cambridge University Engineering De-
   partment, 2006. **[3]**, **[15]**, **[21]**

The numbers [3], [15], [21] are the pages where the used literature is cited.

My preamble is here:

```
\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}
%\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

% the pages of the TOC is numbered roman
% and a pdf-bookmark for the TOC is added
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \frontmatter
  \pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{}
  \myTOC
  \mainmatter }

% makes caption labels bold
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\setcapindent{1em}

% enables calculations
\usepackage{calc}

% fancy page header/footer settings
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{Section \thesection\ #1}}


% increases the bottom float placement fraction
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.5}

% avoids that floats are placed above its sections
\let\mySection\section\renewcommand{\section}{\suppressfloats[t]\mySection}

\pagestyle{plain} 
\newcommand*{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmin}\limits}
```

The bibliography uses IEEETran.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[backref=true]{hyperref}`

Comment: I copied this to preamble but it did not work. I forgot to mention that my Bib style is IEEEtran. Please guide me more!

Comment: Then it would be helpful you create a complete (compilable!) minimal working example showing us all relevant parts for your problem and give us the chance to copy your complete on our computers and to play with ...  Your used documentclass or loaded packages can be a reson for your problem ...

Comment: @HarishKumar's suggestion *should* work. After adding the instruction to the preamble, did you remember to recompile fully (latex, bibtex, and latex twice more) to propagate all changes?

Comment: @Mico: Here is the error after running again and again the file. I dont know what this error is about?   
The package hyperref has already been loaded with options:
  [unicode=true]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [backref=true]
Adding the global options:
  unicode=true,backref=true
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.

Comment: We're starting to make progress. Please tell us how you've specified the `\documentclass` instruction. Separately, have you tried executing the instruction `\hypersetup{backref=true}` instead of trying to set the `backref=true` option when loading the `hyperref` package?

Comment: Hi, It is fixed now after I add \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref} to the preamble.Tks!

Comment: @HarishKumar Would you like to write up an answer (see also last comment by OP)?

Answer (score 2):

The facility you are requesting is provided by the package `hyperref` and `backref` For `hyperref` you have to say

```
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
```

or

```
\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}
```

If you ever get any warning like

```
The package hyperref has already been loaded with options: [unicode=true]
```

try loading the options via `\hypersetup` like

```
\hypersetup{backref}
```

or add `backref` to `\documentclass` options

```
\documentclass[backref]{article}
```

For more details consult the manual of either `backref` or `hyperref` package.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{backref.bib}
@article{Astrm2014,
  doi = {10.1016/j.automatica.2013.10.012},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2013.10.012},
  year  = {2014},
  month = jan,
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
  volume = {50},
  number = {1},
  pages = {3-43},
  author = {Karl J. {\AA}str\"{o}m and P. R. Kumar},
  title = {Control: {A} perspective},
  journal = {Automatica},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\cite{Astrm2014}

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{backref}

\end{document}
```

[image]